# Google Analytics event tracking tag not working

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

I am trying to track a button click on a website on Google Analytics, but even though I entered the event tracking snippet in the page code, the results are not showing on GA.

I have placed the following code in the webpage to track a button click. However, I'm not seeing the results on Google Analytics. Is there anything wrong with the code here?

```
<a href="https://gradadm.usc.edu/apply/" target="_blank" class="button
yellow" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click',
'ApplyNow');">Apply Now</a>
```

Comment: Are you using ga.js, gtag, or GTM to collect pageviews?

Comment: I have used ga.js for each type of conversion

Comment: Do you see, if the onclick event is fired and the call to Analytics is sent? You can check this in developer console / Network tab, or using an extension like Google Analytics debugger.

Comment: The Network tab is not displaying any error.

Comment: Is there a call in the network tab to www.google-analytics.com/collect, which is generated after the click?